Pytorch - sending dataset to cuda breaks the dataloader iterator - TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu()
I am trying to speed up my pytorch training by following the advice from here:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cpu-faster-than-gpu/25343/12
So now, I am sending my trainingdata.data and .targets to cuda before starting training. What I am confused about it how to then use the Dataloader made off of the trainingdata in my train function, as when I try the way I had before (when I was sending individual batches to cuda), I get this error on the iterator of the dataloader:
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

It is erroring on the following line (loader is the dataloader here):
for data, target in loader:

What am I doing wrong? How can I still use the dataloader while also sending the full dataset over to the gpu?
Python version is 3.12, pytorch is 2.3.0+cu121
Also, the error is the same if I dont include the pin_memory var to the dataloader
Full error trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1537, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\TorchTests.py", line 181, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\TorchTests.py", line 169, in main
    train(epoch, model, loaders, device, optimizer, lossFN)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\TorchTests.py", line 41, in train
    for data, target in loaders['train']:
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 631, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 675, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\NueralNetTests\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 143, in __getitem__
    img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

and The code:
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


    _transform = Compose([
        lambda img: rotate(img, -90),
        lambda img: hflip(img),
        ToTensor()
        ])

    trainData = datasets.EMNIST(
        root='data',
        train=True,
        transform=_transform,
        download=True,
        split='letters'
    )
    testData = datasets.EMNIST(
        root='data',
        train=False,
        transform=_transform,
        download=True,
        split='letters'
    )

    trainLoader = DataLoader(trainData,
                             batch_size=100,
                             shuffle=True,
                             pin_memory=True
                             )

    testLoader = DataLoader(testData,
                            batch_size=100,
                            shuffle=True,
                            pin_memory=True
                            )

    trainData.data = trainData.data.to(device)
    trainData.targets = trainData.targets.to(device)
    testData.data = testData.data.to(device)
    testData.targets = testData.targets.to(device)

    model = CNN().to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    lossFN = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    for epoch in range(1, 2):
        train(model, trainLoader, device, optimizer, lossFN)
        test(model, testLoader, device, lossFN)

def train(model, loader, device, optimizer, lossFN):
    model.train()
    for data, target in loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = lossFN(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2Drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 27)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.leaky_relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.leaky_relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2Drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return F.softmax(x)




This question is similar to: TypeError: can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To resolve the issue with sending your entire dataset to the GPU and still using the DataLoader, you should avoid manually sending the data and targets of the dataset to the device. Instead, move each batch to the GPU inside the training loop. This ensures that only the current batch is transferred to the GPU, which is more efficient and aligns with the typical usage pattern in PyTorch.
Try this approach instead:
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import Compose, ToTensor
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.transforms.functional import rotate, hflip

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

_transform = Compose([
    lambda img: rotate(img, -90),
    lambda img: hflip(img),
    ToTensor()
])

trainData = datasets.EMNIST(
    root='data',
    train=True,
    transform=_transform,
    download=True,
    split='letters'
)
testData = datasets.EMNIST(
    root='data',
    train=False,
    transform=_transform,
    download=True,
    split='letters'
)

trainLoader = DataLoader(trainData,
                         batch_size=100,
                         shuffle=True,
                         pin_memory=True
                         )

testLoader = DataLoader(testData,
                        batch_size=100,
                        shuffle=True,
                        pin_memory=True
                        )

model = CNN().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
lossFN = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(1, 2):
    train(model, trainLoader, device, optimizer, lossFN)
    test(model, testLoader, device, lossFN)

def train(model, loader, device, optimizer, lossFN):
    model.train()
    for data, target in loader:
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = lossFN(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

def test(model, loader, device, lossFN):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += lossFN(output, target).item()
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
    
    test_loss /= len(loader.dataset)
    accuracy = correct / len(loader.dataset)
    print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}')

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2Drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 27)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.leaky_relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.leaky_relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2Drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)



Like I mentioned, this is exactly what I had before, but according to the people at the pytorch official forum, my desired changes should make it faster

@FredE Only if the GPU memory can hold all the data (in your case as the MNIST is fairly small), typical dataset can get upto dozens of GB, and doing that will limit the memory for the model itself to train.

@FredE if you want to still keep all that, then you have to change the getitem() method for the dataset taken from the torchvision itself. Read how they do data preprocessing and create a class that inherits the torchvision's dataset and overwrite your own getitem() without converting them to numpy().

@MingNH ah, got it, thank you! That makes sense, I will try something out on that front
